# R: keeping axis labels and scales when plotting multiple graphs

Tags: r, plot, axes

I am using the following formula to plot 5 graphs together :

```
my_data <- as.data.frame(datasets::volcano)

layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 3, 2, byrow = TRUE))
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(my_data$V1, my_data$V2)
plot(my_data$V3, my_data$V4)
plot(my_data$V5, my_data$V6)
plot(my_data$V7, my_data$V8)
plot(my_data$V9, my_data$V10)
plot.new()
```

[image: 5 plots]

It works well but I loose the scale of the y-axis of the 1, 3 and 5th plots and the x-axis of the latter. This keeps happening for any future ones I do until I dev.off().

Thanks!

Comment: increase margins, e.g. `par(mar=c(4,4,1,1))`

Comment: @tpetzoldt Yes that works the right way thanks. Do you know how to reset the ````par(mar)```` after use?

Comment: This is described as first Example at the `par` help page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `par(mfrow = c(3, 2))` and adjust your margins. You may need to increase the size of your window to accommodate the plot

```
my_data <- as.data.frame(datasets::volcano)
par(mfrow = c(3, 2))
par(mar = c(2, 2, 2, 2))
plot(my_data$V1, my_data$V2)
plot(my_data$V3, my_data$V4)
plot(my_data$V5, my_data$V6)
plot(my_data$V7, my_data$V8)
plot(my_data$V9, my_data$V10)
```

[image: p]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately with my actual dataset I get ````Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large````. Would you know how to fit them in?

Comment: Do you user RStudio? If yes, increase the plotting area with the mouse.

Comment: Got it thanks. I actually wasn't clear on how ````par(mar)```` worked but understood now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to *@AllanCameron*'s solution—I'd keep `layout` in mind, since it can be very useful! Also you may want to regard the RStudio "Plots" window as a preview tool. Better save your plots with `pdf` or `png` as shown below; the plot will be saved in your `getwd()`. In addition you may avoid the repeated `plot` call by creating a `sub.cols` data frame which can be looped by an `sapply`.

```
my_data <- as.data.frame(datasets::volcano)
sub.cols <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:10, 2))

png("myPlot01.png", width=400, height=600)
layout(matrix(1:6, 3, 2, byrow=TRUE))
op <- par(mar=c(4.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5))  ## set par and store old par
sapply(sub.cols, function(i) plot(my_data[i]))
plot.new()
par(op)  ## restore old par
dev.off()
```

If the soiled console annoys you you can do `invisible(sapply(.))` above.